# Create unique id per computer and use it as identifier when no user is logged in

Tags: angularjs, django, authentication, local-storage, session-cookies

I am trying to create a web app that would submit ratings to some articles. The backend is django and frontend is angularjs.

A rating is a model with the following properties: rater, value, and article

I would like to let anonymous users to submit ratings, in which case, the rater is null, but a sessionid is attached to the rating object to identify where this rating comes.

Currently, I am using the session module from django, and attaching `session_key` attribute to each rating object. However, this has issue that the session changed if a valid user is logged in and logged off.

What I would like to have is to have a unique identifier for each computer from which the rating is created, and attach this id to the object. So, as long as no user is logged in, the objects created by one computer, regardless of refreshing, rebooting, loggin+logout, etc., share the same identifier.

By doing this, my ultimate goal is to allow anonymous user using the App as if he/she is always logged in. In another word, each computer is a unique "implicit user" when no real user is logged in.

My question is that, is there a way to achieve this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Also, don't keep the sessionid. It is worthless once the session is over. You'd be better off doing something like if request.user: # save with user info else: save without

Comment: How do you define a unique computer? By IP - What if multiple people are behind the same IP, or they change IP? By MAC address - same question?

Comment: @Obj3ctiv3_C_88 I am saving the user info when there is a user logged in. But the question is how to identify an object created by anonymous user.

Comment: You can't track an anonymous user, I mean you can during the session but once that's over you can't. You just set the user to either an umbrella "guest" user or just put it as none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## LocalStorage

Anonymous users can't be tracked perfectly.
Best you can do in my opinion is using `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.setItem('anonymous-key', 'some-key-you-generated');
```

and then whenever no user is logged in:

```
var anonymousKey = localStorage.getItem('anonymous-key');
```

### Persistence

Local storage stays saved until the user specifically clears it. Some browsers may also add a expiry date to your data for safety reasons.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage